# Windows does not accept login password from Recovery Environment

Tags: windows-10, security, privacy, windows-re

Windows 10 won't accept my login password from the **Recovery Environment**. That's the blue screen with options such as **Repair Installation**.

This is despite Windows accepting the same password to log me into the OS from the main login screen at system startup.

I am using the same account to login into the Recovery Environment.

Can anyone advise as to the cause of this error and how to fix it without Resetting the OS install?

Comment: Are you attempting to access an account linked to a Microsoft Account from within WinRE?

Comment: Normally windows recovery should not give you a login. Is it perhaps the login to decrypt an encrypted harddisk?

Comment: The HDD is not encrypted.